# writer string and formula till the data available for particular range

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, loops, xlsxwriter

I have data in excel and wanted to write a string with a sum for each group of the table.
So I wanted to loop through in a range and write a string **"Subtotal"** on the first column and apply formula '=sum{}:{}' from start row to before I'm writing a formula.

I know the start and end range.

How can I achieve that by using a loop where the first blank found write string and formula.

**input:** [image]

See below code I'm trying but it does not work.

```
    row_start = number_rows_placement + number_rows_adsize + 20
        row_end = number_rows_placement + number_rows_adsize + number_rows_daily + unqiue_final_day_wise * 5 + 15
            for i in range ( row_start , row_end ):
                if i == " ":
                    worksheet.write(i,1,"Subtotal", format)
                    i += 5
                    worksheet.write_formula(i,2,'=sum(:)', format)
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't know where I'm wrong. also while trying to get sum range would vary after each header to before the formula marked.

**OutPut:**[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formula isn't valid in Excel. It should be `=SUM()`, uppercase.

Also, you can generate the range for the formula with something like this:

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_range


row_start = 60
row_end = 64
col = 1

cell_range = xl_range(row_start, col, row_end, col)  # B61:B65
```

See the XlsxWriter [Cell Utility Functions](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions).

Comment: thanks for your response. the formula was a typo. well, the concern is here I only know the start and end range but in my case, I want to write a string in between of where the data available. I only know starting but don't how to write string on between the last cell of first dataset to first set of second dataset.